# Característica, que já não é útil, preservada no design de um objecto

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Estava a ler [esta questão e as suas respostas](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99996/what-is-the-word-for-a-property-no-more-necessary-but-still-present-in-a-object), e questionei-me se o Português não teria uma palavra para descrever a mesma noção.

Palavra para designar uma propriedade, ou design, que é resquício do passado, e agora desnecessário.

Cumprimentos.

Comment: "Resquício" e "vestígio" equivalem ao que foi sugerido nas respostas da pergunta linkada, não?

Comment: O objectivo é saber se a palavra 'Skeuomorph' tem um termo equivalente português

Comment: Bem, "skeumorfismo" e "esqueumorfismo" não constam do [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario), mas segundo o Google esses termos têm sido utilizados por aí.

Comment: @bfavaretto - aqui, por exemplo: http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/proximo-ios-tera-design-mais-plano-influenciado-por-jony-ive-diz-wsj/

Comment: Muito gostam de criar termos novos vindos do inglês ;)

Comment: o que não é útil é obsoleto

Comment: Uma característica mantida é uma característica remanescente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu usaria "**vestigial**" na maioria das situações.

Você está usando a palavra *design* em lugar de desenvolvimento pelo que aparenta ser de uma área mais específica, para mim, nesse caso, a melhor opção é usar o jargão. Dependendo do purismo eu usaria ["**esqueumorfismo**" (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esqueumorfismo) como jargão.

Comment: Essa palavra existe?

Comment: Qual? Vestigial, sim, esqueumorfismo provavelmente não está no dicionário, mas em algum texto de design sim.

Comment: Helmut será que pode colocar alguma fonte?

Comment: Esqueumorfismo: OLIVEIRA, Amanda Porto; NÖTH, Winfried. Leitura semiótica dos ícones de aplicativos do iOS. Teccogs: Revista Digital de
Tecnologias Cognitivas, TIDD | PUC-SP, São Paulo, n. 10, p. 124-140, jul-dez. 2014. :P

Comment: Helmut, incluí o link à wikipédia. Se não o quiseres, podes sempre fazer roll-back.